# Nullable List compiles but throws an error every time

Tags: c#, generics

The following line seems fairly simple and compiles but I get an error on the line every time

```
List<long?> persistantIds = new List<long?>();
```

The error message I get is the classic "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

It doesn't make sense why it would error.  Also one odd thing I see is when I view the value in VS2012 the Value shows up as

'' is null

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line, there must be something else in your code causing the error.

Comment: Is this only happening on your release build?  Line numbers in stack traces lose their reliability outside of debug mode.

Comment: Your question is accumulation close votes, I think because many people think that you have not provide enough information for the question may be reasonably answered. (there is nothing wrong with the part of the code you have supplied) I suggest that you create a minimal repro and post it here. That will allow you to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: I am still dumbfounded as to what caused the error as cleaning the solution did not fix the error.  I added spacing and was able to reproduce the error with an error message point to the new line.  After restarting Visual Studio and trying to reproduce it in a standalone project the error finally went away so I am not sure what was causing the Issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using VS 2012.2 and this works great on my machine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<long?> persistantIds = new List<long?>();
    Console.WriteLine(persistantIds.Count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Try doing a clean build and if all else fails, restart VS.